# Is there a way to SELECT using "GREATEST(field1, field2)" where field1 and field2 are aggregate sums in the same select?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a java app calling a query written in HQL, calling postgres. The problem is I want to be able to aggregate (sum) two fields and then project the "greatest" of these aggregations. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/functions-conditional.html for documentation on psql's "greatest"

Is this possible?

I think you might be able to do what is called a "nested aggregate" query by projecting greatest as the output of an inner select? But if this can be written without nesting it would be preferred.

```
select u.id, sum(foo.stat1) as stat1Sum, sum(foo.stat2) as stat2Sum, greatest(stat1Sum, stat2Sum)
from u, foo
where u.id = foo.uid
group by id
```

Running my query results in the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode 
 \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'GREATEST' {originalText=GREATEST}
    \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
       +-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'archiveBytesTotal' {originalText=archiveBytesTotal}
       \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'selectedBytesTotal' {originalText=selectedBytesTotal}
```

I do not think I made any errors on the mapping object, I think the issue lies in the fact hibernate cannot derive the type of the aliases I am using for my sum aggregates.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supported aggregate functions for HQL are:

```
avg(...), sum(...), min(...), max(...)

count(*)

count(...), count(distinct ...), count(all...)
```

See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html

Comment: Ah shoot. I was mislead, greatest is a feature of Postgres and not hibernate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If it's an option to rewrite the query, you may try [FluentJPA](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA), which supports the function you need.